# How to query in sencha based on the textfield value entered?

Tags: sencha-touch, web-sql

I am new to sencha touch. I have a text field where the user types some data:

```
{
                  xtype: 'textfield',
                  id: 'road',
                  placeHolder :'Road',
                  label: 'Road'
                                    },
```

When the user types some value in this and clicks on search it must query the database and fetch result accordingly.

```
xtype: 'button',
text: 'Search',
handler: function() {
   var x=Ext.getCmp('road').getValue();
       alert(x);  // i can get value here.
    db.transaction(
       function (transaction) {

          transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Journal where id=x;', [],display, null);

                           }
                           );
                                    myapp.Viewport.setActiveItem('mylist', {type:'slide', direction:'left'});
                                    }
```

This select query works if i put id=1; but not when id=x which i'm fetching from Ext.getcmp. Here i am getting value in runtime. So at compile time x is null. Please suggest me how to query it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Journal where id='+x+';', [],display, null);
```

This may help you.